# Kubernetes dashboard tls certificates on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster 1.6.1 running with the kuberentes-dashboard (gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.6.1) and I've not been able to update the tls certificates for our domain and the site is showing as not secure.

It is using the kubernetes-master certificate that was created when the cluster was setup with KOPS.

On other deployments/pods I've been able to use a kubernetes secret that has the correct tls.crt and tls.key on the ingress that points to the correct certificate but the dashboard does not use an ingress and I did not see a place to change the certificate on this service.

Where can I either update the default kubernetes-master certificate or just update the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation#recommended-setup

> Custom certificates have to be stored in a secret named kubernetes-dashboard-certs in kube-system namespace. Assuming that you have dashboard.crt and dashboard.key files stored under $HOME/certs directory, you should create secret with contents of these files:

```
kubectl create secret generic kubernetes-dashboard-certs --from-file=$HOME/certs -n kube-system
```